# Returning to the start of a loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have to create a basic three-round rock paper scissors game for my beginners Java class.  I've gotten everything in my code to work except my "Play again?" command.  I know I'm supposed to use a loop for this, but I'm not entirely sure where in the code to insert the loop.  Here's the code I currently have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RPSGameFinal {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!  Best two out of three!");
    System.out.println("Please enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
    int playerWins = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;
    int roundNumber = 0;

    if (roundNumber < 3)
    {
        while (roundNumber != 2)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String playerChoice = keyboard.next();
            if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock"))
            {
                roundNumber = roundNumber + 1;
                Random computerChoice = new Random();
                int choiceValue = computerChoice.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Rock, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Paper, Computer Wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Scissors, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
            }
            else if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            {
                roundNumber = roundNumber + 1;
                Random computerChoice = new Random();
                int choiceValue = computerChoice.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Rock, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Paper, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Scissors, Computer wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
            }
            else if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
            {
                roundNumber = roundNumber + 1;
                Random computerChoice = new Random();
                int choiceValue = computerChoice.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Rock, Computer wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Paper, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
                else if (choiceValue == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Scissors, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\".");
                }
            }
        }
        if (roundNumber == 2);
        {
            Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input2 = keyboard2.next();
            if (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock"))
            {
                Random computerChoice2 = new Random();
                int choiceValue2 = computerChoice2.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue2 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Rock, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Paper, Computer wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rock vs Scissors, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))
            {
                Random computerChoice2 = new Random();
                int choiceValue2 = computerChoice2.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue2 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Rock, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Paper, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Paper vs Scissors, Computer wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors"))
            {
                Random computerChoice2 = new Random();
                int choiceValue2 = computerChoice2.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if (choiceValue2 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Rock, Computer wins!");
                    computerWins = computerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Paper, Player wins!");
                    playerWins = playerWins + 1;
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (choiceValue2 == 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Scissors, Tie!");
                    System.out.println("Player has won "+playerWins+" times and the computer has won "+computerWins+" times.");
                    if (playerWins > computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Player wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?  Enter Yes or No.");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins < computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?  Enter Yes or No.");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (playerWins == computerWins)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Tie game!");
                        System.out.println("Play again?  Enter Yes or No.");
                        Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String input3 = keyboard3.next();
                        if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Which type of loop should I use and where should it be placed?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could put a while loop around your entire game and loop based on a "playAgain" boolean.

Comment: My friend, I'll tell you just this: do you realize your class has a single method made of 570 rows? You're going to regret that when a bug will need to be corrected

Comment: Check out my answer.  That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop right after your main method.

```
int playAgain = 1;
while(playAgain == 1){
//your code
System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no");
//Get User input here and set it to the variable playAgain
}
}//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout the documentation for the "continue" keyword, specifically using "labels".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html
do a "find in page" for "ContinueWithLabelDemo".

Basically, you can label a line to continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean playing = true;
while(playing){
    //your game code
System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    //get user input
if(user said no){
    playing = false;
 }
```

This is a basic outline one how to keep a continuous loop to execute through your program

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code is very long and very difficult to maintain ... a quick fix will be wrap all in a function ( change 'main' to 'game' ) and then add a boolean to the main. this boolean will decide if to run another game :

```
public static void game() { /*all code of main goes here*/ }



public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean quitGame=false;

while(!quitGame){
    game(); // calling to start a game
    System.out.println("Play again?  Enter Yes or No.");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input3 = keyboard.next();
    if (input3.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        quitGame = true; // this will exit the loop 
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

I restructured your code in the hope that you will better understand why I put my loops where I did:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    Random random = new Random();

    System.out.println( "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!  Best two out of three!" );
    boolean playAgain = false;

    do
    {
        int playerWins = 0;
        int computerWins = 0;

        for ( int i = 1; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "Roundnumber: " + i );
            String playerChoice = inputPlayerChoice( scanner );
            int computerChoice = calculateComputerChoice( random );
            RpsResult result = calculateResult( playerChoice, computerChoice );
            boolean isPlayerWin = result.isPlayerWin();
            boolean isTie = result.isTie();

            if ( !isTie )
            {
                if ( isPlayerWin )
                {
                    playerWins++;
                }
                else
                {
                    computerWins++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println( "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer has won " + computerWins + " times." );
        }
        showFinalResult( playerWins, computerWins );
        System.out.println( "Play again?" );
        playAgain = askIfPlayAgain( scanner );
    }
    while ( playAgain );

    System.out.println( "Thank you for playing!" );
    scanner.close();
}
```

If you take a look at the main method you will see, that I put a do-while loop around the mainpart of the program. This is for repeating the whole game again. I choose a do-while loop because you want to run the game at least once.

Since you always want to play exact 3 rounds I also added a for-loop around the inner section. This has the benefit, that you don't need to write your code 3 times - since in all 3 rounds actually happens the same (userInput, calculate computer choice, see if the user or the computer wins this round, write the result of the round on the console)

After the for-loop you show the final result, ask the player if he wants to repeat the game and set the playAgain variable that will break the loop if its false.

---

**For your information:**

This is how I broke your code down to fit the showed main method.

These are the methods to get the player choice and the computer choice:

```
private static String inputPlayerChoice( Scanner scanner )
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\"." );
        String playerChoice = scanner.next();

        return playerChoice;
    }

    private static int calculateComputerChoice( Random random )
    {
        int computerChoice = random.nextInt( 3 ) + 1;
        return computerChoice;
    }
```

This is how the result of a round is calculated - sincs its always the same I moved it to its own method:

```
private static RpsResult calculateResult( String playerInput, int computerChoice )
    {
        boolean playerWin = false;
        boolean tie = false;

        if ( playerInput.equalsIgnoreCase( "Rock" ) )
        {
            switch ( computerChoice )
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println( "Rock vs Rock, Tie!" );
                tie = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println( "Rock vs Paper, Computer Wins!" );
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println( "Rock vs Scissors, Player wins!" );
                playerWin = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if ( playerInput.equalsIgnoreCase( "Paper" ) )
        {
            switch ( computerChoice )
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println( "Paper vs Rock, Player wins!" );
                playerWin = true;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println( "Paper vs Paper, Tie!" );
                tie = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println( "Paper vs Scissors, Computer wins!" );
                break;
            }
        }
        else if ( playerInput.equalsIgnoreCase( "Scissors" ) )
        {
            switch ( computerChoice )
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println( "Scissors vs Rock, Computer wins!" );
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println( "Scissors vs Paper, Player wins!" );
                playerWin = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println( "Scissors vs Scissors, Tie!" );
                tie = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        RpsResult result = new RpsResult();
        result.setPlayerWin( playerWin );
        result.setTie( tie );

        return result;
    }
```

RpsResult is a simple storage Object:

```
public class RpsResult
{
    private boolean playerWin;
    private boolean tie;

    /**
     * @return the playerWin
     */
    public boolean isPlayerWin()
    {
        return playerWin;
    }

    /**
     * @param playerWin
     *            the playerWin to set
     */
    public void setPlayerWin( boolean playerWin )
    {
        this.playerWin = playerWin;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tie
     */
    public boolean isTie()
    {
        return tie;
    }

    /**
     * @param tie
     *            the tie to set
     */
    public void setTie( boolean tie )
    {
        this.tie = tie;
    }

}
```

To print the result message I used this method:

```
private static void showFinalResult( int playerWins, int computerWins )
    {
        System.out.println( "Final result: playerWins " + playerWins + " computerWins " + computerWins );

        if ( playerWins > computerWins )
        {
            System.out.println( "Player has won" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "Computer has won" );
        }
    }
```

And the question if the player wants to play again:

```
private static boolean askIfPlayAgain( Scanner scanner )
    {
        String input = scanner.next();
        if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase( "Yes" ) )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to loop however many times you would like. There are three different kinds that would work here: a for loop, a while loop, or a do while. However, I would suggest using a for loop and just using a boolean operator in the method to decide when you would like for it to stop looping